# Kusto Query Language (KQL) magic and Jupyter Lab connection error during queries

Tags: jupyter-lab, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have been using Kusto Query Language (KQL) and running queries from Jupyter Lab through the help of magic-command %%kql as instructed in the link below:

https://github.com/microsoft/jupyter-Kqlmagic

Lately, I started getting the following error for the same queries that I used to run without any issues. Sometimes when I refresh my jupyter lab and connection to kql, the problem disappears but there doesn't seem to be any consistency and the problem seems to get worse more recently.

The error:
ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

I would appreciate any guidance on how to solve this problem.

p.s. I tried to create the Kqlmagic tag under the tags as recommended in (https://github.com/microsoft/jupyter-Kqlmagic) however the system doesn't allow me to create this new tag as I don't have the required 'reputation score'...

Thank you

Baran

Answer (score 0):

Hi (I am the author of Kqlmagic),
pls install Kqlmagic latest dev version (I think it is dev21), try to replicate the error, once it happens, execute "%kql --bugreport" and submit it to Kqlmagic Github. The bugreport, will help to toubleshoot it.

Comment: Hi Michael, firstly "%kql --bugreport" is not working in the current Kql version. I tried to upgrade it to the latest version but is there a 'install' word missing in the command suggested in this link: https://pypi.org/project/Kqlmagic/. I guess the installation command should have been '!pip install Kqlmagic --no-cache-dir --upgrade' instead of !pip Kqlmagic --no-cache-dir --upgrade' can you confirm? Either way, the first command with 'install' works but kql is only updated to version 0.1.112.pot1 and not the dev25. The command wh 'install' word simply doesn't work. Thank you.